# Run Custom Script after every Code-First Migration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I need to create a multi-column index like so:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserName_Inc_LastOnline_Lat_Long] ON [dbo].[User]
(
    UserName ASC
)
Include (LastOnline, Latitude, Longitude)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

I've found some ways to do this, but nothing that stands out as a way to get exactly the above.  Is there a way to include custom SQL as part of migrations without manually doing `add-migration` and adding the code there?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to run this as part of my `Seed()` method:

```
protected override void Seed(AppContext context) {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AppContext, Configuration>());

        if (!WebSecurity.Initialized) {
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "User", "UserId", "Username", autoCreateTables: true);
        }

        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
            "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = 'IX_UserName_Inc_LastOnline_Lat_Long') " +
            "BEGIN " +
            " CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserName_Inc_LastOnline_Lat_Long] ON [dbo].[User] " +
            " (UserName ASC) " +
            " Include (LastOnline, LocationLat, LocationLong) " +
            " WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) " +
            "END"
        );

        base.Seed(context);
    }
```